# Is this possible to achieve this specific staggered gridview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, staggered-gridview

[image]

This is view that I want to achieve with dynamic number of items. I am using package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view.

I want first item to take full width, then I want others to layout next items as in `MasonryGridView`

I tried to do it with `MasonryGridView` but as documentation said tile `Must occupy 1 column only`.

Other grid layouts like `StaggeredGridView` can do this but in this case I don't see availability to put items using `index` like in `ListView`. Maybe am I missing something here and this is good solution for my case?

Other grid layouts, for example `QuiltedGrid` have possibility to use it with `index`, but they have `pattern` property, which make it my 0 index which taking whole width to repeat, this is not what I want

Is there any solution to achieve what I want?

Comment: @pskink I can have more items, first one has to take full width, then I want others layout  as in ```MasonryGridView```

Comment: @pskink Will ```firstWidget``` scroll then? I need it to scroll with next items also, that's why I am looking for this GridView layout

Comment: no, stop, don't do that, I just took a look into the docs and it seems that you can use https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/SliverMasonryGrid-class.html instead, for more check https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/MasonryGridView-class.html and find `Transitioning to CustomScrollView`

Comment: @pskink can you post example of this as I am being confused with implementing delegates on this solution

Comment: btw `SliverMasonryGrid` has 3 different constructors - you need to find out which one is the best for your particular use case

Comment: I finally understood, I tried with wrong constructor at first, You help me a lot, I achieved what I want, thank you so much, have a nice day

Comment: sure, your welcome, so which constructor you used? `SliverMasonryGrid.count` maybe?

Comment: Yes, ```SliverMasonryGrid.count``` was the best for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with [SliverMasonryGrid](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/SliverMasonryGrid-class.html) sliver it is as simple as this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red)),
        SliverMasonryGrid.count(crossAxisCount: 2, childCount: 20, itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          child: Container(height: i.isOdd? 50 : 80, color: i.isOdd? Colors.green : Colors.blue, child: Center(child: Text('item $i'))),
        )),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(height: 100, color: Colors.orange)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's possible to somehow add padding to ```SliverMasonryGrid```? I was able to add padding to ```MasonryGridView```, adding margin on item even depending on index is not a solution as index % 2 == 0 is not always on left side column

Comment: hmmm, you have to wrap it around another sliver responsible for padding and it's name is .... `SliverPadding`

Comment: ```SliverPadding```, of course xD
Thanks again